# TeXmaker resets its settings every startup

Tags: texmaker, ubuntu

I'm on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 LTS. TeXmaker resets its settings every time it's opened. I've changed the theme, rebound shortcuts, defined custom commands, and changed the PDF viewer. Yet, the `.ini`-file isn't being modified, and the custom settings last for the session only.

I installed Ubuntu GNOME and Texmaker on another computer, and I have no problems there.